# ASP.Net Core with Angular: if endpoints are specified in typescript, how can such a web service run without NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core, endpoint

I'm trying to understand how .NET Angular with typescript fits together with NodeJS (solution created using Microsoft Visual Studio).

If the endpoints are defined in typescript, and if NodeJS is needed to run typescript, how can the solution run without NodeJS installed?  As per threads like: https://groups.google.com/g/angular/c/UjgOvDu0ads  NodeJS is not necessary at runtime...

Answer (score 0):

e.g. IIS can host the webservice that has those endpoints using https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-deploy-angular-app-to-an-iis-web-server-complete-setup-337997486423

also see

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/831752/JavaScript-for-Windows-server-side